# My Laravel Middleware Not Locking Down Correct

Tags: laravel, middleware

I am not sure how to fix this. When I log in as a user, it redirects to my user dashboard. If I try to change the URL from `/user/dashboard` to `/admin/dashboard`, it gives an error saying no admin rights. Perfect, but when I login as admin it does go to the admin dashboard. When I change the URL from `/admin/dashboard` to `/user/dashboard`, the `/user/dashboard` is not protected and it goes to it.

##### AdminMiddleWare

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role_as == '1'){
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('login')->with('status','You Do Not Have Admin Rights');
        }
    }
}
```

##### LoginController

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Login Controller
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
     | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
     | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
     |
     */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    protected function authenticated()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->role_as == '1') {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard')->with('status','Welcome to your Admin Dashboard');
        } else {
            return redirect('/home')->with('status','Welcome To Your User Dashboard');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

##### Routes

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('user.dashboard');
Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware('isAdmin')
    ->name('admin.dashboard');
```

Comment: Hi Todd, probably you are looking for the reverse middleware of isAdmin. I would try to include a middleware in the non-admin routes where the user can't continue if it is an admin and it's being redirected to their admin dashboard.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are applying any middleware to the `user.dashboard` route.

You could also separate your routes into different files and/or apply middleware to route groups.  For example, you could apply middleware to any route name starting with `admin.` or `user.`

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-groups